# Covering the graph of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, graphing-functions, lipschitz-functions

$f:[0,1]→\mathbb{R}, ∣f(x)−f(y)∣≤∣x−y∣ \forall x,y∈[0,1] $.

Show that the graph of $f$ can be covered by rectangles that the sum of their shorter sides is less than $ε$, $ \forall ε>0$.

I am not sure how to conclude this. Of course the constant and linear functions can be covered like this, but I could not come up with a soultion for other functions having this property.

EDIT:
I think one has to show that there is a partition on which in every interval $f$ can be approximated by different linear functions.

Comment: Covered, as in what?

Comment: @Tavish the graph can not be seen because the rectangles are 'on top' of the graph.

Comment: Can the rectangles be placed in any orientation on the graph?

Comment: @Tavish yes, of course!

Comment: take a partition ${x_i}$ of $[0,1]$, then the rectangles $[x_i, x_{i+1}] \times [f(x_i), f(x_{i+1})]$ cover the graph of f. It suffices to take a partition that is as refined as needed

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio Thank you, but when adding up the shorter sides, the sum will be  $\mid f(x) - f(y) \mid $ at least and not ε, I would like to find some covering rectangles which cover the graph and the sum of their sides is ε. (in the case of constant functions one can cover them with a rectangle ε*$\mid x-y \mid$.)

Answer (score 2):

Let partition of $[x,y]$ such that:

$P=\lbrace t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_{n-1},t_n\rbrace$, such that length $\mathcal{l}([x,y])=\frac{y-x}{n}$, now;

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})|\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}|t_{i-1}-t_{i}|=\frac{|x-y|}{n}$ by archimedian property you have that

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}|f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})|\leq \varepsilon|x-y|$

Comment: I think one has to show that there is a partition on which every segment of f can be approximated by some linear function.

Comment: @fourelements, the archimeadean property said "For any $\epsilon>0$ there is a natural number $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$"

Comment: @fourelements, by length I am saying that I choose a partition of equal subintervals. I skipped steps in the development, when you consider the partition equal the $ t_ {i} = x + \frac{\alpha}{n}(y-x) $ the same for $ t_{i-1}$, so $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})|\leq\sum|x+\frac{\apha}{n}(y-x)-x-\frac{k-1}{n}(y-x)|\leq\frac{1}{n}(y-x)\leq\varepsilon|y-x|$$

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})|\leq\sum|x+\frac{\alpha}{n}(y-x)-x-\frac{\alpha-1}{n}(y-x)|\leq\frac{1}{n}(y-x)\leq\varepsilon|y-x|$

Comment: I think: $∑|f(ti)−f(ti−1)|≤∑|x+α/n*(y−x)−x−(α−1)/n*(y−x)|=∑|α/n*(y−x)−(α−1)/n*(y−x)\mid = ∑|1/n*(y-x)\mid=\mid n*(1/n)*(y-x) \mid = \mid y-x \mid$